# Batch file not echoing to text file correctly--Please give me a hand

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that counts from 0-100 and echos 1-100 into a text file. but the first 9 numbers are not echoed, it just says echo is off. Can anyone help?

```
@echo off
:start
set /a count=%count%+1
echo %count%>>file.txt
if %count%==100 goto end
goto start
:end
pause
```

this is the code i am using, and the text output is below.

```
ECHO is off.
10
11
12
13
```

as you see it counts all the way to 100 after the first 9 are skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Add a space between `echo %count%` and `>>file.txt`. `2>` is a redirect operator. [Batch Redirect Operators](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php). Also, add `set count=` before `:start` in-case the var already exists.

You can also use a `For` loop instead of your `goto` and `labels`. - [Batch For Loops](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php)

```
@echo off
:start
set /a count=%count%+1
echo %count% >>file.txt
if %count%==100 goto end
goto start
:end
pause
```

Comment: thanks so much :) also is there any way to remove the blank line at the end of the output text? thanks in advance

Comment: I think the answer here [Deleting last n lines from file using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345964/deleting-last-n-lines-from-file-using-batch-file) will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

the best solution is a reverse order of the arguments:

```
>>file.txt echo %count%
```