# Importing a CSV file into postgres - skip the first 3 line

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I import a CSV file into postgres and make it skip the first 3 line and last line

Is it possible in postgres if yes how ?

Comment: No, you have to preprocess the csv file befor import, or use temporary table

Comment: are you trying to build an automated repeatable process or is this a one time load?

Comment: @samyi trying to build automated repeatable process . each time when load the data

Answer (score 0):

Nope, can't be done. Please file an issue with them.

If you're on *Nix, then you can use tail | head:

```
tail -n+4 file | head -n-1 > newfile
```

If Windows then combine [Batch file to delete first 3 lines of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428692/batch-file-to-delete-first-3-lines-of-a-text-file) and [Deleting last n lines from file using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345964/deleting-last-n-lines-from-file-using-batch-file) then realize the errors of your ways and use unix

Comment: @Shubhambatra You can easily get all unix command line tools for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm And you don't need to create a new file. The `copy` command accepts a program as it source: Check the `PROGRAM` parameter: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html