# Windows Batch, how to remove first line and last line and save as a new text file

Tags: batch-file, text, save

text1.txt

```
20150716
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
END
```

I would like to remove 20150716, then the whole text will move up by 1 line and remove the last particular string "END".
Finally, save as a new file called text1_copy.txt.
Then, file becomes:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Combine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428692/batch-file-to-delete-first-3-lines-of-a-text-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345964/deleting-last-n-lines-from-file-using-batch-file to get an answer

Comment: Thank zedfoxus to post a reference links, i found useful with the first link.
`for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (echo %%a >> newfile.txt   )`
It really remove the first line and remaining lines move up by one.

__But__, for the 2nd link ,i just did't get it ,it may be a little bit complex to me. Any way, i found a solution on how to remove "END" which is using loop and keeping read-in and output to a newfile2.txt line by line until the loop hit "END", i will post my solution later.

Answer (score 5):

This just skips the first line and does not write the last one.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("text1.txt") do > "%%~dpna_copy%%~xa" (
        set "line="
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%a in ('
            findstr /n /r "^" "%%a"
        ') do (
            if defined line (
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                echo(!line:~1!
                endlocal
            )
            set "line=%%a"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
more +1 t.txt|findstr /vX "END" > text1_copy.txt
```

where `more +1` skips the first line
and `findstr /vx "END"` deletes every line, that is exactly `END` (lines like `ENDING` or `THE END` will not be removed)

Answer (score 1):

check the [tailhead.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/tailHead.bat) which will allow you to display lines from file by numbers:

```
call tailhead.bat -file="text1.txt" -begin=2 -end=-2 >newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple .bat file for this called cut.bat

```
set file=%~1
set outfile=%~2
if exist %file% goto Main
:error
echo Invalid File!
goto end
:main
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('more +1 %file%') do (
  if  defined row echo.!row!>> %outfile%
  set row=%%j
)
:end
```

all you do is

call cut.bat test1.txt output.txt

Answer (score 0):

For your case, for the fun, you can to that in 3 pure and simpe DOS command

```
findstr /V "20150716" input.txt > output.1.txt
findstr /V "END" output.1.txt > output.2.txt
copy output.2.txt input.txt
```

For information, using "(20150716|END)" Reges with FINDSTR DOS command seems not working with /V option !

**But using SED command after having installed GOW or CYGWIN is the top**

```
sed -i "1d;$d" input.txt
```

where

- `-i` options force the replacement directly in input file
- `1d` requests removing first line
- `$d` requests removing last line

You can download GOW from [Gow GITHUB](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/downloads)